# Oracle Apex - can't send email with IR

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, interactive

I have configured apex instance to use smtp email, and I can send email with IR when using download option from action menu. But the IR subscription is not sending email. How to troubleshoot problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have determined that APEX is able to send emails, but IR subscriptions are not being done (note: you may have to wait 24 hours before you see anything happen), you should check that the **ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS** scheduler job exists and is enabled and running without error.

You can do this by logging in (as either SYS, or as the APEX_*nnnnnn* user) and running the following queries:

```
select job_name, enabled, state, last_start_date
from all_scheduler_jobs
where job_name = 'ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS';

select status, actual_start_date, errors
from all_scheduler_job_run_details
where job_name = 'ORACLE_APEX_WS_NOTIFICATIONS'
order by log_id desc;
```

The output of the above queries should give further clues on what's failing and why.